# Query generated by LINQ is terrible slow compared by creating your own SQL view

Tags: .net, sql-server, linq, entity-framework-6

I've created the following query with LINQ:

```
var today = DateTime.Today;    
var month = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1);
var first = month.AddMonths(-1);
var last = month.AddDays(-1);

var baseQuery = (from jr in DollarU_JobRuns
                 where (jr.Day >= first && jr.Day <= last)
                 group jr by new { System = jr.SYSU.Substring(0, 2) }
                    into systemGroup
                 let NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded = systemGroup.Sum(x => x.NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded)
                 let NbrOfJobRunsFailed = systemGroup.Sum(s => s.NbrOfJobRunsFailed)
                 select new
                 {
                     System = systemGroup.Key.System,
                     NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded,
                     NbrOfJobRunsFailed,
                     Total = NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded + NbrOfJobRunsFailed
                 }).OrderByDescending(item => item.Total);

var query = baseQuery.Take(10).Concat(
                baseQuery.Skip(10).Select(item => new
                {
                    System = "Others",
                    NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded = item.NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded,
                    NbrOfJobRunsFailed = item.NbrOfJobRunsFailed,
                    Total = item.NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded + item.NbrOfJobRunsFailed,
                }
                )
            )
            .GroupBy(g => g.System)
            .Select(
                g => new 
                {
                    System = g.Key,
                    NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded = g.Sum(x => x.NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded),
                    NbrOfJobRunsFailed = g.Sum(x => x.NbrOfJobRunsFailed),
                    Total = g.Sum(x => x.Total)
                }
            )
            .OrderByDescending(item => item.Total);

query.Dump();
```

which generates the following SQL query:

```
SELECT 
    [Project9].[C5] AS [C1], 
    [Project9].[C4] AS [C2], 
    [Project9].[C1] AS [C3], 
    [Project9].[C2] AS [C4], 
    [Project9].[C3] AS [C5]
    FROM ( SELECT 
        [GroupBy5].[A1] AS [C1], 
        [GroupBy5].[A2] AS [C2], 
        [GroupBy5].[A3] AS [C3], 
        [GroupBy5].[K1] AS [C4], 
        1 AS [C5]
        FROM ( SELECT 
            [UnionAll1].[C1] AS [K1], 
            SUM([UnionAll1].[C2]) AS [A1], 
            SUM([UnionAll1].[C3]) AS [A2], 
            SUM([UnionAll1].[C4]) AS [A3]
            FROM  (SELECT TOP (10) 
                [Project3].[C2] AS [C1], 
                [Project3].[C1] AS [C2], 
                [Project3].[C4] AS [C3], 
                [Project3].[C3] AS [C4]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Project2].[C1] AS [C1], 
                    [Project2].[C2] AS [C2], 
                    [Project2].[C1] + [Project2].[C3] AS [C3], 
                    [Project2].[C3] AS [C4]
                    FROM ( SELECT 
                        [Project1].[C1] AS [C1], 
                        [Project1].[C2] AS [C2], 
                        (SELECT 
                            SUM([Extent2].[NbrOfJobRunsFailed]) AS [A1]
                            FROM [dbo].[DollarU_JobRuns] AS [Extent2]
                            WHERE ([Extent2].[Day] >= '2017-09-01') AND ([Extent2].[Day] <= '2017-09-30') AND (([Project1].[C2] = (SUBSTRING([Extent2].[SYSU], 0 + 1, 2))) OR (([Project1].[C2] IS NULL) AND (SUBSTRING([Extent2].[SYSU], 0 + 1, 2) IS NULL)))) AS [C3]
                        FROM ( SELECT 
                            [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1], 
                            [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [C2]
                            FROM ( SELECT 
                                [Filter1].[K1] AS [K1], 
                                SUM([Filter1].[A1]) AS [A1]
                                FROM ( SELECT 
                                    SUBSTRING([Extent1].[SYSU], 0 + 1, 2) AS [K1], 
                                    [Extent1].[NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded] AS [A1]
                                    FROM [dbo].[DollarU_JobRuns] AS [Extent1]
                                    WHERE ([Extent1].[Day] >= '2017-09-01') AND ([Extent1].[Day] <= '2017-09-30')
                                )  AS [Filter1]
                                GROUP BY [K1]
                            )  AS [GroupBy1]
                        )  AS [Project1]
                    )  AS [Project2]
                )  AS [Project3]
                ORDER BY [Project3].[C3] DESC
            UNION ALL
                SELECT 
                [Project7].[C3] AS [C1], 
                [Project7].[C1] AS [C2], 
                [Project7].[C5] AS [C3], 
                [Project7].[C4] AS [C4]
                FROM ( SELECT 
                    [Project6].[C1] AS [C1], 
                    [Project6].[C1] + [Project6].[C2] AS [C2], 
                    N'Others' AS [C3], 
                    [Project6].[C1] + [Project6].[C2] AS [C4], 
                    [Project6].[C2] AS [C5]
                    FROM ( SELECT 
                        [Project5].[C1] AS [C1], 
                        (SELECT 
                            SUM([Extent4].[NbrOfJobRunsFailed]) AS [A1]
                            FROM [dbo].[DollarU_JobRuns] AS [Extent4]
                            WHERE ([Extent4].[Day] >= '2017-09-01') AND ([Extent4].[Day] <= '2017-09-30') AND (([Project5].[C2] = (SUBSTRING([Extent4].[SYSU], 0 + 1, 2))) OR (([Project5].[C2] IS NULL) AND (SUBSTRING([Extent4].[SYSU], 0 + 1, 2) IS NULL)))) AS [C2]
                        FROM ( SELECT 
                            [GroupBy3].[A1] AS [C1], 
                            [GroupBy3].[K1] AS [C2]
                            FROM ( SELECT 
                                [Filter3].[K1] AS [K1], 
                                SUM([Filter3].[A1]) AS [A1]
                                FROM ( SELECT 
                                    SUBSTRING([Extent3].[SYSU], 0 + 1, 2) AS [K1], 
                                    [Extent3].[NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded] AS [A1]
                                    FROM [dbo].[DollarU_JobRuns] AS [Extent3]
                                    WHERE ([Extent3].[Day] >= '2017-09-01') AND ([Extent3].[Day] <= '2017-09-30')
                                )  AS [Filter3]
                                GROUP BY [K1]
                            )  AS [GroupBy3]
                        )  AS [Project5]
                    )  AS [Project6]
                )  AS [Project7]
                ORDER BY [Project7].[C2] DESC
                OFFSET 10 ROWS ) AS [UnionAll1]
            GROUP BY [UnionAll1].[C1]
        )  AS [GroupBy5]
    )  AS [Project9]
    ORDER BY [Project9].[C3] DESC
```

I've created also a SQL view which provides me the same results:

```
With TopItems As
(
    SELECT SUBSTRING( [SYSU],1,2) AS [System]
            , Sum([NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded]) AS NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded
            , Sum([NbrOfJobRunsFailed]) AS NbrOfJobRunsFailed
            , Sum([NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded] + [NbrOfJobRunsFailed]) AS Total
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Sum([NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded] + [NbrOfJobRunsFailed]) DESC) AS Num
    FROM [dbo].[DollarU_JobRuns]    
    WHERE  [Day] >= DATEADD(month, -1, DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0))
            AND [Day] < DATEADD(month, DATEDIFF(month, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING( [SYSU],1,2)


)
SELECT [System], NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded, NbrOfJobRunsFailed, Total
FROM TopItems
WHERE Num <= 10
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    'Others'
    , Sum([NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded]) AS NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded
    , Sum([NbrOfJobRunsFailed]) AS NbrOfJobRunsFailed   
    , Sum(Total)
FROM TopItems
WHERE Num > 10
```

When comparing the results first of all I find that my own crafted SQL view is more concise.
But I like to create LINQ statements and it is also quite concise but the SQL query generated is very big and not understandable.
But whatever is generated (it is anyway under the hood) is not so much important as long as the performance is fine.
But the SQL view has an execution time of 27.5 ms which is a lot faster than 120.3 ms of the query generated by LINQ.

Is LINQ so bad to use or do I miss something to make it more performant?

Comment: I'm not using LINQ too often, but general advise is when you really care about performance - use Stored Procedures for selected queries.
In this particular case seems like LINQ does not support partitioning (window) function.

Comment: Agree with @KamilNowinski  LINQ is not magic.  You can also trip it up with conversions and expressions without noticing too much.  My rule of thumb is to use it for OLTP & key access type operations and leave the aggregations and non-obvious stuff (whatever that means) for procedures

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a defect in EF query translation of the 2 `let` statements using group aggregates. You can try using multiple projection instead:

```
var baseQuery = DollarU_JobRuns
    .Where(jr => jr.Day >= first && jr.Day <= last)
    .GroupBy(jr => new { System = jr.SYSU.Substring(0, 2) })
    .Select(systemGroup => new
    {
        System = systemGroup.Key.System,
        NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded = systemGroup.Sum(x => x.NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded),
        NbrOfJobRunsFailed = systemGroup.Sum(x => x.NbrOfJobRunsFailed),
    })
    .Select(item => new
    {
        item.System,
        item.NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded,
        item.NbrOfJobRunsFailed,
        Total = item.NbrOfJobRunsFailed + item.NbrOfJobRunsFailed
    })
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.Total);
```

so the final query now translates to:

```sql
SELECT
    [Project5].[C5] AS [C1],
    [Project5].[C4] AS [C2],
    [Project5].[C1] AS [C3],
    [Project5].[C2] AS [C4],
    [Project5].[C3] AS [C5]
    FROM ( SELECT
        [GroupBy3].[A1] AS [C1],
        [GroupBy3].[A2] AS [C2],
        [GroupBy3].[A3] AS [C3],
        [GroupBy3].[K1] AS [C4],
        1 AS [C5]
        FROM ( SELECT
            [UnionAll1].[C1] AS [K1],
            SUM([UnionAll1].[C2]) AS [A1],
            SUM([UnionAll1].[C3]) AS [A2],
            SUM([UnionAll1].[C4]) AS [A3]
            FROM  (SELECT TOP (10)
                [Project1].[C3] AS [C1],
                [Project1].[C1] AS [C2],
                [Project1].[C2] AS [C3],
                [Project1].[C4] AS [C4]
                FROM ( SELECT
                    [GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1],
                    [GroupBy1].[A2] AS [C2],
                    [GroupBy1].[K1] AS [C3],
                    [GroupBy1].[A2] + [GroupBy1].[A2] AS [C4]
                    FROM ( SELECT
                        [Filter1].[K1] AS [K1],
                        SUM([Filter1].[A1]) AS [A1],
                        SUM([Filter1].[A2]) AS [A2]
                        FROM ( SELECT
                            SUBSTRING([Extent1].[SYSU], 0 + 1, 2) AS [K1],
                            [Extent1].[NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded] AS [A1],
                            [Extent1].[NbrOfJobRunsFailed] AS [A2]
                            FROM [dbo].[DollarU_JobRuns] AS [Extent1]
                            WHERE ([Extent1].[Day] >= @p__linq__0) AND ([Extent1].[Day] <= @p__linq__1)
                        )  AS [Filter1]
                        GROUP BY [K1]
                    )  AS [GroupBy1]
                )  AS [Project1]
                ORDER BY [Project1].[C4] DESC
            UNION ALL
                SELECT
                [Project3].[C4] AS [C1],
                [Project3].[C1] AS [C2],
                [Project3].[C2] AS [C3],
                [Project3].[C5] AS [C4]
                FROM ( SELECT
                    [GroupBy2].[A1] AS [C1],
                    [GroupBy2].[A2] AS [C2],
                    [GroupBy2].[A2] + [GroupBy2].[A2] AS [C3],
                    N'Others' AS [C4],
                    [GroupBy2].[A1] + [GroupBy2].[A2] AS [C5]
                    FROM ( SELECT
                        [Filter2].[K1] AS [K1],
                        SUM([Filter2].[A1]) AS [A1],
                        SUM([Filter2].[A2]) AS [A2]
                        FROM ( SELECT
                            SUBSTRING([Extent2].[SYSU], 0 + 1, 2) AS [K1],
                            [Extent2].[NbrOfJobRunsSucceeded] AS [A1],
                            [Extent2].[NbrOfJobRunsFailed] AS [A2]
                            FROM [dbo].[DollarU_JobRuns] AS [Extent2]
                            WHERE ([Extent2].[Day] >= @p__linq__2) AND ([Extent2].[Day] <= @p__linq__3)
                        )  AS [Filter2]
                        GROUP BY [K1]
                    )  AS [GroupBy2]
                )  AS [Project3]
                ORDER BY [Project3].[C3] DESC
                OFFSET 10 ROWS ) AS [UnionAll1]
            GROUP BY [UnionAll1].[C1]
        )  AS [GroupBy3]
    )  AS [Project5]
    ORDER BY [Project5].[C3] DESC
```

Comment: This solves the performance problem.
Now the query by LINQ you are suggesting is even faster than my hand crafted view.

1) SQL View  ==> SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 31 ms,  elapsed time = 28 ms.
2) LINQ      ==> SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 15 ms,  elapsed time = 12 ms. 
3) BAD LINQ  ==> SQL Server Execution Times:
   CPU time = 594 ms,  elapsed time = 282 ms.

Comment: Is it possible to explain a little bit more of what is generated by the bad LINQ and the good LINQ?

Comment: The main difference is that if you search the "bad" query, there are 4 `FROM [dbo].[DollarU_JobRuns]` vs 2 in "good" query.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you create a view closer to your business domain and consider referring that view in your EF model.